# Symfony: Save all fields of a form

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this form, which is being created dynamically (using a foreach loop), now I want to save all elements of that form, but I don't know how. The form works correctly, but I don't know how to loop through each submitted field and save each one.

Here's the form:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData);

        foreach($information as $f){
            $form->add(
                $f->getInfoid()->getInfoname(), 
                TextType::class, 
                array('label' => $f->getPartidoPartId()->getPartNom(),

                    )
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the form created from your FormBuilder you can just call `getData()` to retrieve the data you want to loop over.

If your `$defaultData` is an array then you will get an array from `$form->getData()`. If you pass in an object you will get the object back. Since you already pass an object you can also just "reuse" `$defaultData` as changing the values in the form also affects the original object. This does not work with arrays.

Comment: Hi there! I actually solved by using "if($form->has('element_field'))" {do things}